# Application down after some time with proxy error

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, httpd.conf, http-proxy

I am facing one issue constantly on the server. I have deployed the node js application. It's working fine for few hours after that automatically it goes down. It is showing proxy error in apache logs:

[image]

Comment: [Wed Dec 26 19:06:12.815803 2018] [proxy_http:error] [pid 24133] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client 106.204.123.18:6596] AH01102: error reading status line from remote server localhost:3001, referer: https://www.greenr.com/en/
[Wed Dec 26 19:06:12.815878 2018] [proxy:error] [pid 24133] [client 106.204.123.18:6596] AH00898: Error reading from remote server returned by /marketplace_fetch_app_configuration, referer: https://www.greenr.com/en/

Comment: Also check below your question, there's [edit] link